# How can I draw a microfigure on paper?

Tags: microfigure

I am a great drawer, but I cannot draw microfigures! You may think that because I am young I won't be great I really am, but I need help drawing this, on paper.

Comment: Whilst it's not in our sites interest to discuss drafting, I think it can be a very important tool for creative design. I think this is a good question for our site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you'll be working at a scale you may prefer to use graph paper. You can print your own if you don't have any, this will make it easier. Use a ruler, pencil and a rubber to draw your microfigure.

A microfigure is roughly 2/7 legs, 2/7 torso and 3/7 head high, It should also be 3 squares wide. You may find the diagram below makes it easier to visualise:

[image]

At this stage the most important thing to concentrate on is symmetry.

> Symmetry is common in nature, human beings and even more so with Lego.
>   Bricks wouldn't be as compatible as they are now if they didn't have a
>   sense of symmetry.

For now, concentrate on the vertical symmetry (top-to-bottom). In my sketch I've drawn out the three boxes first and added a few rough outlines within the guidelines. These guidelines can be erased later when you have finished.

[image]

If you can draw Microfigures, you can draw Minifigures. All it takes is a change of scale.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

1. [How to Draw a Lego Minifigure with Easy Step by Step Drawing Tutorial](http://www.drawinghowtodraw.com/stepbystepdrawinglessons/2011/08/how-to-draw-a-lego-minifigure-with-easy-step-by-step-drawing-tutorial/)
2. [How to Draw LEGO Men](http://www.ehow.com/video_7411098_draw-lego-men.html)
3. [How to Draw a LEGO](http://www.dragoart.com/tuts/5607/1/1/how-to-draw-a-lego.htm)

Personally number 3 looks like the best bet to me.

Comment: The instructions in these links could be adapted for the micro-figure rather then the minifigure, although they are more "representations" of figures.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid doh, I got the wrong figure type.